# Как работает этот блок кода?

Tags: c++

Учу **C++**, ради эксперимента решил написать прогу, которая бежит по памяти и выводит нули и единицы.

0 - все из следующих 8 битов равны 0, 1 - минимум один из следующих 8 битов равен 1.
Вот код:

```
bool array[1] = {};
for (int i = 0;;i++) {
    cout << array[i] << ' ';
}
```

Запустив, увидел, что проскакивают числа вроде 240 и т.п. Можете расписать, как работает этот код? Почему байты в памяти не преобразуются в `bool`, если мы как бы берем из массива `bool` значений? Как работает этот код?

P.S. Вопрос возник потому, что если мы сделаем массив `char` вместо `bool`, байты будут преобразоваться в символы, так почему тогда байты не преобразуются в `bool`?

Для наглядности два скриншота с выводом:

**bool array:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**char array:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что только элементы массива  имеют такой тип, а попытка  доступа за пределы массива, не имеет никакого отношения с типами элементов массива, и вы просто получите неопределенный результат. Вы скорее получаете целочисленное значение следующего байта

Comment: *"байты будут преобразоваться в символы"* - нет

Comment: @VTT я только что попробовал, могу скриншоты приложить, может я не так выразился, мне просто понять, что происходит уровнем ниже

Comment: Так дело в том, что ничего не происходит. В лучшем случае у вас вычитывается кусок стека после массива, но вычитываемые байты интерпретируются как содержащие данные того же типа, что и в массиве. В случае с `char` символы печатаются потому что вызывается `operator <<` перегруженный для типа `char`, а не потому, что что-то преобразуется в символы. Так или иначе, это все не работает и просто так бегать по незанятной памяти в С++ не получится.

Comment: @VTT спасибо за комментарий, он прояснил все! поставлю ответ вам)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот код не работает, так как на второй итерации происходит чтение за пределами массива, что является Неопределенным Поведением.

Что касается печати чисел вроде 240, то печать `bool` вполне может быть реализована представлением `bool` как целочисленного типа.

Comment: у меня работает почему-то, успевает вывести несколько сотен строк, потом выдает `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Comment: @Maxgmer Получение какого-то вывода не говорит о том, что код работает. Собственно аварийное завершение программы это явно не подпадает под категорию "код работает"

Comment: [у меня работает почему-то] Чтение за пределами массива чаще всего не приводит к краху программы (но иногда и приводит к краху), но тем не менее чтение за пределами массива таки да, является Неопределенным Поведением. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Первая и самая очевидная проблема в том, что в бесконечном цикле трогаете память за пределами массива, и как было упомянуто чтение за пределами массива является Неопределенным Поведением.
Ну и конечно же здесь bool array[1] = {}; происходит инициализация массива нулем (фигурные скобки), и вы получаете вполне ожидаемый результат на итерации array[i] , где  i - это 0.

Answer (score 0):

Никакого преобразования здесь и не должно быть, так как array[i] **уже** имеет тип bool. Тип char отличается тем, что все его значения **интерпретируются** потоком как символы. А bool интерпретируется условным оператором, логическим оператором и операторами циклов. И здесь возможны три варианта:

1. одно значение интерпретируется как false, другое – как true, при остальных значениях поведение не определено;
2. одно значение интерпретируется как false, остальные – как true;
3. одно значение интерпретируется как true, остальные – как false.

Какой из них выбрали авторы стандарта конкретно c++ – вопрос отдельный. Но если значения bool интерпретируются как логические значения ещё и потоком, то выводиться будут только false, true и, может быть, undefined. А вывод чисел однозначно указывает, что поток интерпретирует bool как обычный числовой тип, а не логический.
Могли, кстати, и не выбирать, а отдать на усмотрение авторов компиляторов.
Попробуйте:

```
uint8_t *p;

for (p=((uint8_t*)(&p)); ; ++p)
{
 if ((*p)==0)
 {
  std::cout<<0<<" ";
 }
 else
 {
  std::cout<<1<<" ";
 }
}
```

. Код гарантированно упадёт, но успеет вывести только ноли и однёрки.

Comment: А почему половина значений не может интерпретироваться как `false`, а другая половина как `true`?